# Ontology Tree view using web app

Tags: javascript, treeview, ontology

My goal is to parse an OWL file, show the hirarchy using a tree view in a website. I found one possibility: use JOWL. JOWL javascript library and it is too old and many of the functions are obsolete.

What can be the best javascript option to handle OWL file ? Thank you in advance for suggestion.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? If you did, please share it here!